# How to get height in pixels of LinearLayout with layout_weight

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layoutparams, android-layout-weight

this is my first post. I am learning to code in java for android apps.
I am using a LinearLayout "variable named: ll" with a predefined layout_weight (which I want to change whenever I want in the future) and height and width set to MATCH_PARENT. I want to get the height of this LinearLayout in pixels. I fill this using java (ll.addView(variableForAnObject);).
I am trying to get its height using ll.getLayoutParams().height; but I am getting -1. Because I believe this is the constant for MATCH_PARENT. Setting the height to 0dp makes the ll invisible and gives height as 0.

Please tell me if there's a way to get its height. I think I can do this by getting screen height using DisplayMetrics and making nearly impossible calculations (for me, at least) but this will be too complex.

Comment: `ll.getLayoutParams().height` returns one of `MATCH_PARENT` or `WRAP_CONTENT`. the former is -1 the latter is -2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try with `ll.getHeight()` should work

if not, it's because android has not yet calculed its bounds, then:

```
//inside of onCreate method should work
ll.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //maybe also works height = ll.getLayoutParams().height;

        height  = ll.getHeight();

    }
});
```

Comment: `//maybe also works height = ll.getLayoutParams().height;` no it does not

Comment: Thanks a lot! one problem that's still there is that I get a 0 on the first run. I fill the layout and do much more stuff using a custom method and call this method in OnCreate. But on the first run, I get 0, then if I refill this layout using the same method again, the height then gets a value. I use ll.removeAllViews(); before filling the layout.

Comment: @javi I tried putting directly in onCreate as well as inside my method (which is inside onCreate) but always get a 0. I will search on this matter.

Comment: can you write the layout file, please? I will test on my computer

Answer (score 3):

It is -1 because its dimensions have not yet been set, whenever you set layout it takes some time to compute the actual values including height, width etc.

Use `OnLayoutListener` to listen when it has finished with the layout.

```
layout.onLayoutChange (View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
    //Extract values here
    height = view.getHeight();
    width = view.getWidth()
}
```

See [this](http://java.labsoft.dcc.ufmg.br/apiminer/static/docs/reference/android/view/View.OnLayoutChangeListener.html) for more about the OnLayoutListener

Answer (score 0):

Define your LinearLayout in your class and use getHeight() and getWidth(). Example:

```
LinearLayout yourLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.yourLL);
double height = yourLayout.getHeight();
double width = yourLayout.getWidth();
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Give the `id` field in your layout xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/<ID>>
```

Use this id to get reference in java class and find height and width:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.<ID>);
double height = linearLayout.getHeight();
double width = linearLayout.getWidth();
```